# How to get ui-router state parameters from resolved data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How do I get parameters for a state from a service?
I have this state:

```
.state('cashbox.list', {
        title: 'Cashbox',
        url: '/:from/:to?q',
        templateUrl: '/cashbox_list.html',
        controllerUrl: 'controllers/CashboxCtrl.js',
        controller: 'CashboxCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'mainCtrl',
        params: {
            from: getCashboxParamFrom,
            to: getCashboxParamTo
        },
        resolve: {
            cashboxData: getTransactionsData
        }
    })



    function getTransactionsData($stateParams)
    {
        return CashboxService.getTransactions($stateParams.from, $stateParams.to);
    }
```

Now my problem is, that params *from* and *to* are dynamic and are fetched by another service. I need something like a resolve before the resolve to get the params. I already tried to operate with promises in *getCashboxParamTo/From* but the app then stops routing when going to state. Also tried to use a parent state with *redirectTo* into child state but don't find anything on how to dynamically create stateparams from resolved data in parent state.

```
        .state('cashbox', {
            title: trns('title.cashbox_list'),
            url: '/cashbox',
            redirectTo: {
                state: 'cashbox.list',
                params: HERE DATES FROM RESOLVE
            },
            resolve: {
                dates: getFromToDates
            }
        })
```

Solutions with *state.go* won't work as I'm running into a 'The transition has been superseded by a different transition' issue.

Comment: How about you create two revolvers, and make one dependent on the another one. So, second one will wait until first one is finished, thats the way to get params before calling service in second resolver.

Comment: I need this redirection as resulting URL is needed for deeplinking. Nested resolves will bring up correct data for the state, but browsers address should show up underlying parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to declare two states *cashbox* and *cashbox.list*. Then redirect in a *onStart* transition hook after fetching data from service:

```
$transitions.onStart({to: 'cashbox'}, function (trans)
    {
        var curMonth = gfService.getCurrentMonth();
        return $state.target('cashbox.list', {from: curMonth.dateFrom.string, to: curMonth.dateTo.string})
    });
```